# Change cell fill color based on font color

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

I need to move conditionally formatted data from Excel 2013 into pre-existing tables in PowerPoint 2013. The font colors and formatting will carry from Excel to PowerPoint, but the cell fill needs to be manually added.

Is it possible to create a macro in PowerPoint that will search through each table's cell, find one of five specific font colors "(xxx,xxx,xxx)", then fill that cell with a specified color?

I have tables in Excel that have conditional formatting colors with the following rules:

- "Dark Green "
  Fill: (146, 208, 80)
  Font color: (79, 98, 40)
- "Light Green"
  Fill: (195, 214, 155)
  Font color: (80, 98, 40)
- "Grey"
  Fill: (242, 242, 242)
  Font color: (166, 166, 166)
- "Light Pink"
  Fill: (230, 185, 184)
  Font color: (150, 55, 53)
- "Dark Pink"
  Fill: (217, 150, 148)
  Font color: (149, 55, 53)

One way I can get the cell font and fill to stay is by creating a new chart, but that gets tedious when it needs to be done nearly a hundred times.

Ideally, I would like the macro to search through a presentation, if it finds a table cell value's font as (Dark green) (79, 98, 40), fill that cell to (149, 208, 80). Then continue searching for the next four colors as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()

    Dim s As Slide, p As Presentation, shp As Shape
    Dim rw As Row, cl As Cell

    For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In s.Shapes
            If shp.HasTable Then
                For Each rw In shp.Table.Rows
                For Each cl In rw.Cells
                    ProcessCellColors cl
                Next cl
                Next rw
            End If
        Next shp
    Next s

End Sub

Sub ProcessCellColors(c As Cell)
    Dim tf As TextFrame, clr As Long
    Set tf = c.Shape.TextFrame
    clr = -1
    If tf.HasText Then
        'assumes all text has the same color...
        Select Case tf.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB
            Case vbBlack: clr = vbYellow 'my testing
            Case RGB(79, 98, 40): clr = RGB(146, 208, 80)
            Case RGB(80, 98, 40): clr = RGB(195, 214, 155)
            '....etc etc
        End Select
        If clr <> -1 Then
            c.Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = clr
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is fantastic and works very well.  Would it search for the five specific font colors only in tables, or will it attempt to fill shapes, text boxes, and/or spreadsheets when opening "edit data" in charts?

Comment: I've never used charts in PPT, so you'd have to test that, but I'm guessing it wont affect them.  Regular shapes/textboxes should be unaffected, since it checks each shape using `HasTable`

Comment: As given, it will only affect tables because of the "If shp.HasTable Then" line.