# VBA PowerPoint Cell Color

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I need to figure out whether a specific cell in a powerpoint (ppt) table is Yellow or Not. How can I do that? I know how to change the color of a cell to a particular color. But having hard time to check whether a specific cell is Yellow or not. Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Without any code in your post, it is not easy to assist you, but this link may get you started:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575369/change-cell-fill-color-based-on-font-color

Comment: Reading the color is the opposite of assigning the color...

Comment: For the Below Code

Comment: For lRow = 1 To oSh.Table.Rows.count
            For lCol = 1 To oSh.Table.Columns.count
                Set oCell = oSh.Table.Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape
                MsgBox (oCell.Fill.ForeColor.RGB)
            Next    ' column
        Next    ' row

Comment: Below is what i get for each color
65535 - Yellow
5287936 - Green
255 - Red
12566463 - Gray
But there could be different variations of Yellow. How can I cover all variations of Yellow?

Comment: I want to identify all cells which looks like "Yellow" color. They are not created programatically. These are created by users by selecting the colors from Toolbar.

Comment: I'm not sure you can easily judge "yellow"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to have the RGB values of the colour. Assuming "myColour" hold the colour you want to test, you get the RGB values like this:

```
redValue = myColour Mod 256
greenValue = myColour \ 256 Mod 256
blueValue = myColour \ 65536 Mod 256
```

You then need to make sure that the three values result in a colour that we would call yellow. I suggest redValue and greenValue be above 200, while blueValue is below 100.

Comment: Hi Nomad, That worked perfectly for Yellow. what would be the values that I should look for Green and Red? I mean the ranges for each co-ordinates?

Comment: If redValue > 200 And greenValue > 200 And blueValue < 100 Then
        MsgBox ("Yellow Found in Row " & lRow)
    End If
    
    
    If redValue < 100 And greenValue > 100 And blueValue > 100 Then
        MsgBox ("Blue Found in Row " & lRow)
    End If
    
    If redValue >= 255 And greenValue = 0 And blueValue = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Red Found in Row " & lRow)
    End If
    
    If redValue = 0 And greenValue > 100 And blueValue < 100 Then
        MsgBox ("Green Found in Row " & lRow)
    End If